# Deallocating object that holds mutex while locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, deadlock

I ran into a problem with mutexes that are stored in instances. To give an example, I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <thread>
#include "Sleep.h"

struct Test
{
    std::shared_mutex mutex;
};

Test* test = new Test();

void t1()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(test->mutex);
    SLEEP(200);
    delete test;
    std::cout << "thread 1" << std::endl;
}

void t2()
{
    SLEEP(100);
    std::cout << "hold" << std::endl;
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(test->mutex);
    std::cout << "thread 2" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread trd1 = std::thread(&t1);
    std::thread trd2 = std::thread(&t2);
    trd1.join();
    trd2.join();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What I want is that as soon as `test` is deleted and with it the mutex *reference*(?) the *shared_lock* unlocks. The goal is to make the deletion of an object, which is used by multiple threads, thread safe. As for what happens after the *shared_lock* isn't important (I am aware that I cannot use `test` there anymore).

The output is:

```
hold
thread 1
(here should be 'thread 2')
```

But unfortunately, `t2` seems to deadlock.

#### Questions

1. Is there a way to make the `shared_lock` continue after `unique_lock` runs out of scope? (It is important that the mutex of the instance is used)
2. While testing, I also tried replacing the `shared_mutex` with a `shared_timed_mutex`. For my surprise it causes a crash at the end of `t1()`. Why is that?

Comment: Sawing off the limb that you're standing on is never a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're invoking Undefined Behavior by deleting the mutex held by the `unique_lock` while the lock is still using the mutex.

From the language standard, description of the `unique_lock` class (§ 30.4.2.2):

> The behavior of a program is undefined if [the mutex held by the lock] does not exist for the entire remaining lifetime of the unique_lock object.

You have to destroy or release the lock before destroying the mutex (or class that contains the mutex).